# Repackage .apk for BlackBerry - sign and publish

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I have an Android .apk which is BlackBerry-10 compatible according to their online check tool. I have a BlackBerry developer account and received 2 .cjs files via email (RDK and PBDT). What are my next steps to convert my .apk into a BlackBerry-10 compatible format, sign it and publish? What software do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [online repackaging tool](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) or the BB [Eclipse plug-in](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/install_plugin_prerequisites_1895476_11.html).

Comment: yeah but what about signing and publishing?

Comment: This *will* sign it. Pubishing? From here: https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/login_input.do?pageId=0&csrfToken=MQHT-TT5Y-1R01-1IAO-GAUC-GQSS-BGHZ-G1Y3

Comment: @Ahmad ... Hello doing the same thing as mentioned in http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/install_plugin_prerequisites_1895476_11.html this doc , I have Eclipse Juno Version ..but I am not able to download & Install the Blackberry_Android plugins ..pls help me